# Using WHERE in a multiple query

Tags: php, duplicates, where-clause, multiple-tables

**This is based on a search engine**

I am receiving duplicate search results from this...

```
$construct ="SELECT * FROM Rating, Attraction WHERE $construct" ;
```

---

Then I was informed that it was selecting all results and rows and therefore repeating it so i used this query from another page I have and added the relevant WHERE on the bottom.

```
$construct  = "SELECT Attraction.*, Type.TypeName, Rating.RatingUrl ";
$construct .= "FROM Attraction ";
$construct .= "INNER JOIN Type ON Attraction.Type = Type.TypeID ";
$construct .= "INNER JOIN Rating ON Attraction.AttractionID = Rating.AttractionID ";
$construct .= "WHERE Attraction = '$construct' ";
```

Have do i structure this correctly, it is not working and recognising the query.

**$construct is a query for matching keywords with the database**

Comment: Print out the final string of the query, it's much easier to see errors, and tell us which RDBMS you are using, MySQL?

Comment: In `WHERE Attraction = '$Construct' ` , Attraction is a database field or is it the table name?

Comment: attraction is the table name.

Comment: When debugging a SQL issue, the most important bits of info are: 1) DBMS 2) Actual SQL code. You've omitted both.

Answer (score 1):

The var you store your query in is called `$construct` and you are also including it on the last line `"WHERE Attraction = '$construct' "` so you are actually including the first 4 lines inside the last line, which wont give desired result.

Perhaps renaming the query variable to make it work is enough.

Also if you dont want duplicates, just use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Rating, Attraction WHERE $construct
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because of this

```
 $construct .= "WHERE Attraction = '$construct' ";
```

U are using the same variable name ?

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but please user group by TypeID  may be its work